# Pygame: card game drawing too many cards

Tags: python, function, pygame, append

I posted this yesterday but I failed to provide enough context for anybody to do any proper analysis.  I am trying to make a card game, code for which I have been posting on this site (thank you to everybody who as helped).  I have coded to the point where clicking the end button initiates the draw phase defined by the function drawPhase() and initiated towards the end of the game loop code . I have made it so that each player draws two cards, but for some reason it is trying to draw four times that amount, creating a crash because cards are out of index. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import os
from pygame.locals import*

WINWIDTH = 1200
WINHEIGHT = 800
CARDTHUMBWIDTH = 50
CARDTHUMBHEIGHT = 80
FPS = 30
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('NBA Card Game')
pygame.init()



lakersDeck = ['Lakers_01.png', 'Lakers_02.png', 'Lakers_03.png', 'Lakers_04.png', 'Lakers_05.png',
              'Lakers_06.png', 'Lakers_07.png', 'Lakers_08.png', 'Lakers_09.png', 'Lakers_10.png',
              'Lakers_11.png', 'Lakers_12.png', 'Lakers_13.png', 'Lakers_14.png', 'Lakers_15.png',
              'Lakers_16.png', 'Lakers_17.png', 'Lakers_18.png', 'Lakers_19.png', 'Lakers_20.png']


#shuffling deck, getting first hand, deleting drawn cards from deck
shuffleDeck = random.sample(lakersDeck, len(lakersDeck))
playerDeck = shuffleDeck
playerHand = []
playerHand.append(playerDeck[0])
playerHand.append(playerDeck[1])
playerHand.append(playerDeck[2])
playerHand.append(playerDeck[3])
for cards in range(4):
    del playerDeck[0]

oppShuffleDeck = random.sample(lakersDeck, len(lakersDeck))
oppGetDeck = oppShuffleDeck
oppGetHand = []
oppGetHand.append(oppGetDeck[0])
oppGetHand.append(oppGetDeck[1])
oppGetHand.append(oppGetDeck[2])
oppGetHand.append(oppGetDeck[3])
for cards in range(4):
    del oppGetDeck[0]

#display playmat etc
textPromptFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Lato-Regular", 30)
textPromptRect = "20, 730"
playMat = pygame.image.load('playmat.png')
endButton = pygame.image.load('End Button.png')
detailBox = pygame.image.load('detailBox.png')
DISPLAYSURF.blit(playMat, (0,0))
DISPLAYSURF.blit(endButton, (775, 675))

#defining images and rects            
HAND_IMAGES = {
0: pygame.image.load(playerHand[0]),
1: pygame.image.load(playerHand[1]),                         
2: pygame.image.load(playerHand[2]),
3: pygame.image.load(playerHand[3])}

OPP_HAND_IMAGES = {
0: pygame.image.load(oppGetHand[0]),
1: pygame.image.load(oppGetHand[1]),                         
2: pygame.image.load(oppGetHand[2]),
3: pygame.image.load(oppGetHand[3])}

HAND_RECTS = [pygame.Rect(17, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(75, 635, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(133, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(191, 635, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(249, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(307, 635, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(365, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(423, 635, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(481, 635, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(539, 635, 50, 80)]

OPP_HAND_RECTS = [pygame.Rect(17, 80, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(75, 80, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(133, 80, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(191, 80, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(249, 80, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(307, 80, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(365, 80, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(423, 80, 50, 80),
         pygame.Rect(481, 80, 50, 80), pygame.Rect(539, 80, 50, 80)]

END_RECT = [pygame.Rect(775,675, 110, 110)]

oppHandPos = [(17, 80), (75, 80), (133, 80), (191, 80), (249, 80), (307, 80), (365, 80), (423, 80), (481, 80), (539, 80)]
playerHandPos = [(17, 635), (75, 635), (133, 635), (191, 635), (249, 635), (307, 635), (365, 635), (423, 635), (481, 635), (539, 635)]
defStep = [1]

##drawText("Choose a card for your bench.", textPromptFont, DISPLAYSURF, 20, 725)
##pygame.display.update()

class Text:
    def __init__(self, text, font, surface, x, y):
        self.text = text
        self.font = font
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def draw_text(self):
        text_obj = textPromptFont.render(self.text, 1, (0,0,0))
        text_rect = text_obj.get_rect()
        text_rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        self.surface.blit(text_obj, text_rect)

text_prompt_enter_draw_phase = Text("Click the End Button to enter the Draw Phase.", textPromptFont, DISPLAYSURF,20,725)
text_prompt_choose_for_bench = Text("Choose a card for your bench.", textPromptFont, DISPLAYSURF, 20, 725)

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def drawPlayMat():
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(playMat, (0,0))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(endButton, (775, 675))

def displayHand(hand, oppHand):
    handCount = len(hand)
    for card in range(handCount):
        cardThumb = pygame.image.load(hand[card])
        cardThumb = pygame.transform.scale(cardThumb, (50,80))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(cardThumb, playerHandPos[card])
        handCount = len(hand)
    oppHandCount = len(oppHand)
    for card in range(oppHandCount):
        cardThumb = pygame.image.load(oppHand[card])
        cardThumb = pygame.transform.scale(cardThumb, (50,80))
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(cardThumb, oppHandPos[card])    
    pygame.display.update()

def updateHandImages():
    tempHand = hand
    finTempHand = {}
    newTempHand = [pygame.image.load(t) for t in tempHand]
    for i in range(0,len(newTempHand)):
        finTempHand[i] = newTempHand[i]
    return finTempHand

def drawPhase():
    drawHand = hand
    drawDeck = deck
    oppDrawHand = oppHand
    oppDrawDeck = oppDeck
    drawHand.append(drawDeck[0])
    drawHand.append(drawDeck[1])
    oppDrawHand.append(oppDrawDeck[0])
    oppDrawHand.append(oppDrawDeck[1])
    for cards in range(2):
        del drawDeck[0]
        del oppDrawDeck[0]
    return drawHand, drawDeck, oppDrawHand, oppDrawDeck

##def benchPhase():
##    benchHand = hand
##    benchDeck = deck
##    benchBench = []
##    
##    .append(deck[0])
##    for cards in range(2):
##        del drawDeck[0]
##    return drawHand, drawDeck


#game loop
while True:
    # defining image indexes
    currentHandImageIndex = None
    endButtonIndex = None

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    #game loop variables
    hand = playerHand
    oppHand = oppGetHand
    deck = playerDeck
    oppDeck = oppGetDeck
    benchHand = []
    oppBench = []
    postHand = []
    oppPost = []
    perimeterHand = []
    oppPerimet = []
    showHand = displayHand(hand, oppHand)
    handImages = updateHandImages()


    #stage variables
    step = defStep
    isDrawPhase = False
    isBenchPhase = False
    isRecruitPhase = False
    isAttackPhase = False

    #text_prompt_choose_for_bench.draw_text()
    endButtonPressed = False    
    mouseClick = False

    #text drawing
    if len(step) == 1:
        isDrawPhase = True
        text_prompt_enter_draw_phase.draw_text()
    if len(step) == 2:
        isBenchPhase = True
        text_prompt_choose_for_bench.draw_text()

    #defining exit protocol and mouse click
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouseClick = True

    #getting card indexes for image loading
    for i, rect in enumerate(HAND_RECTS):

        if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            currentHandImageIndex = i
            break

    for i, rect in enumerate(END_RECT):

        if rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            endButtonIndex = i
            break

    #defining what happens on mouse click for images and defining when end button is clicked        
    if mouseClick == True:
        if endButtonIndex is not None:
            endButtonPressed = True
        if currentHandImageIndex is not None:
            if currentHandImageIndex <= len(hand)-1:
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(handImages[currentHandImageIndex], (925,200))

    #Draw Phase protocol
    if isDrawPhase == True:
        if endButtonPressed == True:
            hand, deck, oppHand, oppDeck = drawPhase()[0], drawPhase()[1], drawPhase()[2], drawPhase()[3]
            endButtonPressed = False
            isDrawPhase = False
            step.append(1)
            drawPlayMat()

    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()




pygame.display.update()
```

Thanks in advance and again, truly appreciate it.

Comment: Please read the [mcve] section in the help. You've given us a ton of irrelevant code, haven't told us which part of the code is doing the drawing, having shown us the exception, or described anything beyond "it's creating a crash".

Comment: thanks @abarnert.  Last time I didn't give enough code and it seems I've vomited code this time, hopefully I'll get the hand of this soon.

Comment: Using SO effectively really isn't as easy as it looks. That's why the help section is so extensive—but even after reading it, it's still not always obvious what you should do. If you're, say, a beginner who's never helped a classmate with their code, it's hard to imagine the mindset of the people who want to help, and it can be hard to persevere when you often don't get the answers you want while you're still figuring it out, but it usually doesn't take much practice to get it.

Comment: But meanwhile, when you get comments, downvotes, or close votes, edit your question to improve it. You may not get the votes back, but you may get an answer you wouldn't have otherwise gotten, which is a lot more important.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this line of your `drawPhase()` function :

```
 hand, deck, oppHand, oppDeck = drawPhase()[0], drawPhase()[1], drawPhase()[2], drawPhase()[3]
```

if you index in this way, the function will be called again for every time you index it, causing 2 cards to be appended to the deck 4 times, instead of being append 1 time.

if you want the four output values of the function stored in `hand, deck, oppHand oppDeck`, you can replace the above line of code with this line :

`hand, deck, oppHand, oppDeck = drawPhase()`

this line stores all the return values in the variables `hand, deck, oppHand, oppDeck` and this way the function is only called once.